# how to write log from a app?

Tags: android, logging

Please tell me how to write errors/exceptions to log from a app deployed in a device?
My app is a service and i got logcollector app, but it is not showing any log data.
I tried writing to log as

```
Log.e("MyAppTag: ", "HttpException: " + exp.toString());
```

But not getting anything in log

Comment: that is exactly how you log stuff. You just have to log in your logcat.

Comment: Yes from eclipse, DDMS i checked logcat, but didnt seen my log data. @JanDragsbaek.

Comment: for testing purpose you add a dummy log Log.i("","in oncreate"); in your onCreate method of your service. If it will work fine than the problem is not your log but in some condition which you check before print the log

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/debugging-log.html

Comment: This is the way. There is nothing wrong with the code, so there must be some other mistake. Have you connected your device, have you selected your device, do you see other log messages, does the application reach this line of code?

Comment: @Niek Yes so much data is coming in the log, of other various application. I am checking the log as my app is getting force close sometime. Thanks for the valuable suggestions. Let me try.

Comment: if your log doesn't display anything , it happends to me sometimes, so open the DDMS Perspective, and in the select your device or your emulator from the zone at left , and you will see the logCat loaded on the LogCat Tab .